# exec-maven-plugin cannot be started before compile phase

Tags: python, maven, maven-plugin, exec-maven-plugin

I want to write addtional texts to the Java resource files (combine two .java files to one). And I write a python script to do so.

I also want to automate the steps (combines files, compile, package) using Maven. I am a newbie to Maven, I found that `exec-maven-plugin` could run the python script.

I tried to set`<phase>process-resources</phase>` to try to make it start before compile, but Eclipse complained that `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec 
 (execution: default, phase: process-resources)`

below is my pom of the exec-maven-plugin:

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-resources</phase> <!-- Eclipse complains an error here -->
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <executable>python</executable>
            <workingDirectory>src/main/python</workingDirectory>
            <arguments>
                <argument>combine.py</argument>
            </arguments> 
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Anyone know that how could I implement this purpose? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Eclipse M2e plugin trick. `Sachin Shekhar R` is right, but the answer is not clear enough for newbies like me. Here comes my understanding:

See http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered.
There are two methods to do so in Eclipse M2e.

1. use the code listed in `Sachin Shekhar R`'s answer. Notice that this piece of code must under `<pluginManagement><plugins>` and `<pluginManagement>` must be inside `<plugins>`. sample code：

   ```
   <build>
   <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <!-- plugins here-->
               </plugin>
   </plugins>
   <pluginManagement>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
               <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.0</version>
               <configuration>
                   <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                       <pluginExecutions>
                           <pluginExecution>
                               <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                   <versionRange>[1.2.1,)</versionRange>
                                   <goals>
                                       <goal>exec</goal>
                                   </goals>
                               </pluginExecutionFilter>
                               <action>
                                   <ignore/>
                               </action>
                           </pluginExecution>
                       </pluginExecutions>
                   </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
   </build>
   ```

   This only works in the project.
2. use the "Quick Fix" feature of the Eclipse M2e plugin. It exists after version 1.0. Find the error in `Problems` tab. Right click on it, select "Quick Fix". There would be a Quick Fix window popping up, select the second option `Mark goal exec as ignored in Eclipse build in Eclipse references (experimental)`.
   This method would write above code between `<lifecycleMappingMetadata>` into workspace profile of lifecyclemapping into `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml` 
   This works in the entire workspace

Answer (score 2):

We have similar code generation under

```
<execution>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

And under plugins we also have additional entries to avoid eclipse complain

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.codehaus.mojo
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        exec-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.2.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>java</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution></pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Live example from GWT source code for lifecycle mapping- `http://code.google.com/searchframe#T04cSGC7sWI/trunk/samples/expenses/pom.xml`

Reference Explanation - stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin

Comment: I tried your code, but the errors still exists. I put them under the <plugins> in the same pom.xml file as the exec plugin, is that right?

Comment: Updated answer with link to sample pom from GWT source code. Also, read on reference explanation.

Comment: Above code cannot deal with it. I read from http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered and found `HINT: m2e provides a quick-fix associated with "plugin execution not covered" to easily create <pluginManagement/> elements like above.` That helped me. I will take some snapshots to answer

Comment: Oh, found it finally, this pom.xml is so long. And finally I know that your code must added inside `<pluginManagement><plugins>`, which is inside `<plugins>`. If not, it would not work. And the wiki page named two methods. the quick fix one is the automatic way to add this code

Comment: exactly :D . The devil always lies in the detail. GWT docs/example are improving ( but they are a long way off from being simple )